# Scala filter with wildcard?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a filter with wildcard, example: `df.filter($"dst_ip"==="1.1.1.*")`. Somehow, when I do `df.show()`, it returns blank. Is there an alternative on how to do wildcard filter on a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a `contains`:

```
df.filter($"dst_ip".contains("1.1.1."))
```

Or if you want the string at the beginning, you can use the `like` just as in SQL:

```
df.filter($"dst_ip".like("1.1.1.%"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the syntax at first. I got it now with your help above.